# angular dropdown list not populating

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to populate my angular dropdown menu with "events(birthday,meeting etc.)", but it does not seem to populate. I wanted to achieve something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/

Here is my html markup and angular controller:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Event Type</label>
    <div>
        <select data-ng-model="seleectedEvent" data-ng-options="options for options in eventOptions"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

//controller

```
ngCalendarApp.controller("calendarDayCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.eventOptions =
    [
        "Birthday",
        "Meeting",
        "Project"
    ];
    $scope.initialise();
});// End calendarDayCtrl controller
```

Does anybody have a clue as to why it is not populating

Comment: Where is your **seleectedEvent** model inside of your controller and also are you spelling it correctly?

Comment: I fixed it using this statement:                                     $scope.selectedEvent = $scope.event_state[2];